# How to fill in and return a `DataTable` from a method with `try` and `using`?

Tags: c#, ado.net

To fill `DataTable`, I use the method that is presented below.
In the line `adapter.Fill (table_2);` i get an error:
`The value can not be undefined. Parameter Name: dataTable`.

**Question:** How to fill in and return a `DataTable` from a method with `try` and
`using`?

**My Code**

```
 static DataTable CreateCmds_1()
        {
            DataTable table_2 = new DataTable();
table_2 = null;
            try
            {
              string connectionString = @"Data Source=SRV2\SQLEXPRESS1;Initial Catalog=Prb;Integrated Security=true"; // 

                string queryString = "SELECT * FROM tbl_01_Groups";



                using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
                {
                    SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
                    adapter.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);
                    SqlCommandBuilder builder = new SqlCommandBuilder(adapter);

                    connection.Open();

                    // DataTable table_3 = new DataTable();

                   adapter.Fill(table_2);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                string s = ex.Message;
                string t = ex.StackTrace;
                // throw;
                Console.WriteLine(s);
                Clipboard.SetText(s);

                Console.ReadLine();
            }

            return table_2;
        }
```

Comment: Did you tried to remove line `table_2 = null;`?

Comment: @Fabio Your answer is correct.
Works